# How can I hear sound playing while scrubbing the audio from an <audio> tag?

Tags: html, audio, web-audio-api, audiocontext

In my example, I have a mp3 that a user has uploaded to a webpage. I create a visual waveform on the page and have all the default controls coded and working (play, pause, stop, scrubbing, etc...)

What I'm trying to accomplish is the scrubbing effect that you hear in After Effects or Animate. When I scrub the audio, I want to hear the tones of the audio at the exact place where the scrubber is.

I don't even know where to begin on this? I looked into `AudioContext` and I think my answer is in there somewhere but I'm not sure. I've thought about having a "shadow audio tag" that I set the same src to and then calling `play()` and pausing it pretty soon after but that seems like a mess; especially with an aggressive scrubber. Any direction would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes your answer is in the AudioContext API (all async and slow MediaElements are not made for this). Specifically, what you want is the [AudioBufferSourceNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioBufferSourceNode/) interface, which is able to play audio instantly.

All you need to do is to fetch your audio file as an ArrayBuffer, ask an AudioContext to [decode the audio PCM data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BaseAudioContext/decodeAudioData) from this buffer and create an AudioBuffer from it.

That was the heavy part, but it's done only once.

Then you just need to create a very-light *AudioBufferSourceNode* for each "scrub" event.
To do so, you can use the three arguments version of its [`start(when, offset, duration)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioBufferSourceNode/start) method.

```js
const slider = document.getElementById('slider');
const ctx = new AudioContext();

fetch("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/d/dc/Strawberry_Fields_Forever_(Beatles_song_-_sample).ogg")
  .then( resp => resp.arrayBuffer() )
  .then( buf => ctx.decodeAudioData(buf) )
  .then( prepareUI )
  .catch( console.error );
  
function prepareUI( audioBuf ) {
  let source;
  slider.oninput = e => {
    if( source ) { source.stop(0); }
    source = ctx.createBufferSource();
    source.buffer = audioBuf;
    source.connect(ctx.destination);
    const offset = slider.value * audioBuf.duration;
    const duration = 0.1;
    source.start(0, offset, duration);
  };
  slider.disabled = false;
}
```

```css
input { width: 350px }
```

```html
<input type="range" id="slider" min="0" max="1" step="0.005" disabled>
```

And of-course you can also reuse this AudioBuffer for your whole player.

Comment: Wow...I would have never have figured that out. Thanks so much! I had to tweak it a little for my scenario but it totally works and accomplishes what I needed. ✋

Answer (score 0):

I think you're on the right track.  Your scrubber UI could interact with an `Audio` element that is not attached to the DOM/page and could directly set [`audio.currentTime`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/currentTime), play for a few milliseconds, and then stop.  You can leverage cancellation of `setTimeout()` queues to create short scrubbing playbacks and then play continuously when the scrubbing stops.  I assume this all depends on the complete file being downloaded to avoid network latency during scrubbing.